# jquery: history.back(1) issue

Tags: jquery

I have an issue with jquery and history.back(): I got a link:

```
<a href="#" id="backLink">Link back</a>
```

I cant use something like href="javascript:history.back()" as the CMS used is blocking inline JS (for whatever reason).

So I place a JS like this:

```
$("#backLink").click(function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    history.back(1);
});
```

But this does not seem to work! On Safari and Chrome no problem, but on FF, IE this link is not working!

Is there a way how to use this for all browsers - or is there some mistake in the above code?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Probably you are missing to specify `event` as function argument, try specifying that too:

```
$("#backLink").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    history.back(1);
});
```

In other words, you had problem on `event.preventDefault();` which most likely prevented below code from running or working.

Answer (score 0):

An easy method:

```
 <a href="javascript: history.go(1)" id="backLink">Link back</a>
```

Answer (score -2):

I'd try:

```
javascript: history.back(1)
```

otherwise using:

```
javascript: history.go(1)
```

the browser will stay where it is. That's not really what was initially requested, is it?