# browser back button and get the url of the page on which back button is pressed

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to get url of previous page when some user has clicked browser back button and is redirected to previous page. jquery or rails

Comment: Answer of your question is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3528324/how-do-you-get-the-previous-url-in-javascript

Comment: Please try to be polite.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11339812/1932751).

I think you just have to use this jQuery code :

```
$("#backLink").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    history.back(1);
});
```

where #backlink is the selector of your button.