# Cordova 5.1.1 app backward navigation

Tags: android, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

I am developing an Cordova Android application with jQuery mobile. I did override the back button click, but backward navigation is not happening. This is my code:

```
onBackButtonTap : function(event){
        navigator.app.backHistory();
}
```

When I press the back button, the call is coming to the above function but the application is not navigating back. Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1):

@Dineshchakkravarthi,
you need to trap the [backbutton event](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/cordova/events/events.html). This link will get you the correct page in the documentation -> *Cordova* [backbutton](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.0.0/cordova/events/events.backbutton.html).

Here is the quik example:

```
document.addEventListener("backbutton", onBackKeyDown, false);

function onBackKeyDown() {
    // Handle the back button
}
```

Comment: i have implemented the backbutton trap. That method is getting triggered when i taps the backbutton. inside that i have used navigator.app.backHistory(). But navigation is not happening.

Comment: hMMM.. that was NOT part of your question. There are bugs in some the webview engines. The reference is not always the same. If you google [backhistory](https://www.google.com/search?q=backhistory), then w2schools says use `window.history.back`. A little further down you will see a BUG: [CordovaSim: Need to implement navigator.app.backHistory](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/JBIDE-15814) that bug is *closed*. Meaning, it is no longer a bug.

Comment: If you google [jquery backhistory](https://www.google.com/search?q=jquery+backhistory), then you get [jquery: history.back(1) issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339781/jquery-history-back1-issue). This may be your answer